# Are MySql Stored Procedures preferable to Prepared Statements?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

Is it correct that prepared statements should be considered a less effective means of improving db performance than stored procedures because stored procs persist across sessions while prepared statements do not?  In other words, prepared statements get re-compiled and cached per session?

I realize that there's a few questions on this site about this but none seem to address this specific question.  No need to comment on the comparison other than in regards to this specific question.

Comment: Premature optimization? The bottleneck in most database applications is scanning the tables, not parsing the query. Have you done everything you can to optimize the query, and this is really the only way to wring any more time savings?

Comment: And you still need to use a prepared statement to supply parameters to the procedure.

Comment: @Barmar - understood and that is how i proceed. but i would like to know the answer to this question at the same time. even if it saves me .1% i shall take it.

Comment: .1% is a WAY BIG number to gain from such a difference. If you need to save, I could tell you what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of cases, the performance difference is negligible.

The real performance savings using a stored procedure comes from reducing the number of round trips to the database, when the stored procedure is performing multiple SQL statements.

If a stored procedure is wrapping a single SQL statement, and it's being called from the application in place of a single SQL statement, then it's unlikely there is any performance benefit with MySQL. (There may actually be a little more work for MySQL to do calling the stored procedure.)

Where we usually get a performance boost with a stored procedure is reducing the number of statements executed by the client; that is, eliminating some of the statement "execute" calls.